# Getting error in azure powershell while creating new storage account using the command New-AzStorageAccount

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

```
$storageAccount = New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name "blobstgaccdemo" -SkuName Standard_LRS -Location $location

New-AzStorageAccount : An error occurred while sending the request.
At line:1 char:19
+ ... geAccount = New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -N ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzStorageAccount], HttpRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.NewAzureStorageAccountCommand
```

Comment: Its not clear what the error is. Are you missing parts of the error?

Comment: Using the -Debug flag may also help get some useful information about the error.

Comment: @Swabha Is this happening with other cmdlets as well or just this one? Are you on the latest version of `Az` module?

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic error and can occur in more than a few conditions, including when Azure PowerShell is not able to reach/resolve the underlying management REST APIs, or in case of SSL errors.

To get more information about the error, run the PS cmdlet passing the `-Debug` parameter along, or set `$DebugPreference` to **Continue** before executing the cmdlet. This would surface the details of the exception along with the stack trace.

If this is consistently happening with other cmdlets as well, then you could try upgrading PS modules, or re-installing Azure PowerShell itself. Another quick alternative would be to use [Azure Cloud Shell](https://shell.azure.com/powershell) that is preconfigured with all the required modules.